# Does anyone know of a script to convert pygtk to tk

Tags: python, pygtk, tkinter

I have a fairly large work project that uses pygtk for the GUI and I need reduce the dependencies and convert to tkinter.

Does anyone know of a script to convert exisiting pygtk code to tkinter?

Comment: Their underlying programming models of the two GUI toolkits are _so_ different that I'd be astonished if any such automatic translation was feasible -- I fear you'll have to do it by hand:-(.

Comment: Found a possible solution PyGtk2Tk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for anyone in the same boat as me, I just found [PyGtk2Tk](https://code.google.com/p/pygtk2tk/) which is a PyGtk to Tkinter Wrapper that runs PyGtk based code unchanged using Tkinter (Tk).

Comment: I'll be testing later this week (work project is non urgent) but from what I can read ( https://code.google.com/p/pygtk2tk/wiki/MainPage ) the script supports the following classes/Widgets (GObject / Object / Widget / Container / Bin / Window / Box / HBox / VBox / Table / Button / ToggleButton / CheckButton / RadioButton / Label / Entry ) which I believe cover the majority of what the work project uses, any thing else I will either do by hand or most likely code up and submit to PyGTK2TK.

Comment: Testing has been positive, but work project has been placed on the backburner till the new year.